# How to pass multiple parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using onclick event to perform some acction, but for som reason the second ID is not being passed what am I doing wrong here:
                `row += '<td>' + data[staff].Naame + '(<a href="#" class="name" code="' + data[staff].place + '">' + data[staff].place1 + 'fID="' + data[staff].id+ '"' +'</a>)</td>'`

```
    $(document).on("click", ".name", function (e) {
        var code = ($(this).attr("code"))
        var fID = ($(this).attr("fID"))
        function(code, fID);
            });
```

For some reason fID is not being passed from `'fID="' + data[staff].id+ '"'` to `function(code, fID);` why is that?

Comment: what's this ..? `function(code, fID);`

Comment: Some extra semi-colons would be "nice" on your var declarations :) You also do not needs the outer parenthesis.

Comment: You can't call an anonymous function like that.

Comment: Please place the space before FID string concate

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that invokes some function onclick name class. I know there is no problem with that function. The problem is in my `row` I am not sure if my `""''` correct in `row`?

Comment: you fID is not a prop or attr to the '.name' element. you need to set things in order first and then use or pass it to a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define fID within the `<a ... >` tag - like you are doing for code.

ie:

```
<a href="#" class="name" code="' + data[staff].place + '" fID="' + data[staff].id + '"> ... </a>
```

Comment: This is correct but in `fID` it says `undefined` does that means nothing is being returned?

Comment: Can you do console.log(fID); (or alert(fID);) after your line var fID = ... - to see what value it has. Per one of the other comments, I'm not sure what function(code, fID) is doing...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using loads of string concatenation in jQuery, to create elements, as it is generally unreadable and leads to typing mistakes (*like not putting the fId inside the tag attributes*):

Instead build the element with jQuery. I am not 100% sure of what your link should look like from the code, but something like this (tweak to suit):

```
var $td = $('<td>').html(data[staff].Naame);
$td.append($('<a>', {class: 'name', code: data[staff].place, fId: data[staff].id}).html(data[staff].place1));
row.append($td);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
row += '<td>' + data[staff].Naame + '<a href="#" class="name" code="'+data[staff].place+'" fID="'+data[staff].id+'">'+data[staff].place1+'</a></td>'
```